# Need one value in a big string in sqlserver

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Need Sqlserver query.

Example 1:

> { "Id": 1785, "Type": 10, "Vendor": "vendor1", "Brand": "brand1",
>   "LOB": 0, "Category": "Supported", "Name": "Security Bulletin",
>   "MarketVersion": "WW17-150", "InternalVersion": "1.0", "Edition": "",
>   "Role": "", "CDIVersion": "", "BuildVersion": "", "Patch": "",
>   "Hotfix": "", "Arch": "x86", "ReleaseDate": "2017-09-29", "Released":
>   1, "Locale": "en-us", "Tag": "", "ConfigDetails": "", "Description":
>   "Security-Only update for Windows (KB4038779, KB4038786, KB4038793)",
>   "Notes": "Wonderware Security Bulletin WW17-085", "UpdateDate":
>   "2017-09-29", "ExceptionStatement": "dddddd"}

Example 2:

> { "Id": 783, "Type": 10, "Vendor": "vendor1", "Brand": "brand1",
>   "LOB": 0, "Category": "Supported", "Name": "Security Bulletin",
>   "MarketVersion": "WW17-085", "InternalVersion": "1.0", "Edition": "",
>   "Role": "", "CDIVersion": "", "BuildVersion": "", "Patch": "",
>   "Hotfix": "", "Arch": "x86", "ReleaseDate": "2017-09-29", "Released":
>   1, "Locale": "en-US", "Tag": "", "ConfigDetails": "", "Description":
>   "Security-Only update for Windows (KB4038779, KB4038786, KB4038793)",
>   "Notes": "Note: All Microsoft KB#s listed in the table above are
>   supported with Wonderware products listed under Mainstream Support. 
>   *Note: KB4038779 is Security-Only update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.
>   *Note: KB4038786 is Security-Only update for Windows Server 2012.
>   *Note: KB4038793 is Security-Only update for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2.",  "UpdateDate": "2017-09-29", "ExceptionStatement":
>   "dddddd"}

Example 3:

> { "Id": 1859, "Type": 1, "Vendor": "Microsoft", "Brand": "", "LOB": 0,
>   "Category": "", "Name": "Windows", "MarketVersion": "30",
>   "InternalVersion": "", "Edition": "Embedded Standard", "Role": "",
>   "CDIVersion": "", "BuildVersion": "", "Patch": "SP1", "Hotfix": "",
>   "Arch": "x86", "ReleaseDate": "2017-11-21", "Released": 1, "Locale":
>   "en-us", "Tag": "", "ConfigDetails": "", "Description": "desc",
>   "Notes": "notes", "MsSecurityLink": "", "InformationLink": "",
>   "UpdateDate": "1900-01-01", "ExceptionStatement": ""}

In the above json string there is 'Type' attribute.  I need the value of the Type.  For example1 the output should be 10 and in the second example also the output should be 10 and in the third example the output should be 1.

Please help the sqlserver query.

Comment: 1. Install SQL Server 2016. 2. Use [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql). 3. ??? 4. Profit!

Comment: my requirement in sqlserver 2008 r2

Comment: If you can't use sql server 2016, use [T-SQL string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql) to look for the Type and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
DECLARE @json varchar(1000)='{ "Id": 1785, "Type": 10, "Vendor": "vendor1", ...}'

DECLARE @pos1 int=NULLIF(CHARINDEX('"Type": ',@json),0)+LEN('"Type": ')
DECLARE @pos2 int=CHARINDEX(',',@json,@pos1)

SELECT @pos1,@pos2,CAST(SUBSTRING(@json,@pos1,@pos2-@pos1) AS int)
```

In the query

```
SELECT pos1,pos2,CAST(SUBSTRING(json,pos1,pos2-pos1) AS int) [Type],json
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      NULLIF(CHARINDEX('"Type": ',json),0)+LEN('"Type": ') pos1,
      CHARINDEX(',',json,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('"Type": ',json),0)+LEN('"Type": ')) pos2,
      json
    FROM
      (
        SELECT '{ "Id": 1785, "Type": 10, "Vendor": "vendor1", ... }' json
        UNION ALL SELECT '{ "Id": 783, "Type": 10, "Vendor": "vendor1", ...}'
        UNION ALL SELECT '{ "Id": 1859, "Type": 1, "Vendor": "Microsoft", ...}'
        UNION ALL SELECT '{"IdLeft": 255, "TypeLeft": 0, "IdRight": 284, "TypeRight": 0, "RelationshipType": 1, "Description": "" }'
      ) q
  ) q
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  First query worked for me.  But in one scenario it fails.

Comment: my Json has two formates one is mentioned one and another is below one.{"IdLeft": 255, "TypeLeft": 0, "IdRight": 284, "TypeRight": 0, "RelationshipType": 1, "Description": "" }.  I should not consider this type of json string and should consider "{ "Id": 1785, "Type": 10, "Vendor": "vendor1", ...}".  in this case query fails and got exception "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ft": 255' to data type int.
". Please help me.

Comment: I changed my answer. Try to test it again. I return `NULL` if `Type` not found.